# Cannot switch from Intel to Nvidia GPU somehow

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus

I'm trying to get the GPU GeForce 940M on my new HP laptop ENVY 17-n101ng running, but have somehow extreme troubles switching from Intel to Nvidia. I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (16-bit). I have installed the Nvidia driver `nvidia-331` from the command line (tried the same before with `nvidia-361`):

```
sudo apt-get install nvidia-331 nvidia-prime
```

but the command

```
sudo prime-select nvidia
```

gives me the following errors:

```
Error: alternatives are not set up properly  
Error: nvidia mode can't be enabled
```

I had to start a new branch, since I have not found a suggestion which could help me. Can it be resolved on a software side or I need to switch graphic cards in BIOS somehow?

Comment: Welcome to Ubuntu. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (16-bit)? 32 or 64 bit are the options.

Answer (score 1):

You should install and use the [latest stable drivers](http://www.nvidia.com/download/driverResults.aspx/97645/en-us) supporting your NVIDIA GEFORCE 940M card.

Remove the drivers 331 - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
sudo reboot
```

Install the drivers 352 - open a terminal and execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352 nvidia-prime
sudo reboot
```

In case it still doesn't work, repeat everything from a virtual console ...

Highlight the Ubuntu entry in the GRUB boot menu and press the <kbd>E</kbd> key.
Add `nouveau.modeset=0` to the end of the `linux` line - press <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot.
On the login screen press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> - enter your user name and password.
Now execute the commands as they are already instructed in the main part above.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your quick reply!!! Done... but unfortunately nothing has changed... still the same problem... I cannot perform sudo prime-select nvidia... Do you have any other ideas? I'm quite lost at the moment...

Comment: @user3631541 : Does it work when you open NVIDIA X Server Settings -> PRIME Profiles ? Maybe NVIDIA graphics are already in use - you can see it there - you can also check it with this command : lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' - when the output says kernel driver in use : nvidia, you already are using NVIDIA graphics. :)

Comment: no... it does not work this way either...  The command gives the following output:                                                                                                                            00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 1916 (rev 07)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 80e6
 Kernel driver in use: i915_bpo
--
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation Device 1347 (rev a2)
 Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 80e6
 Kernel driver in use: nvidia

Comment: The NVIDIA driver is not running properly, no sample from NVIDIA CUDA can be launched giving the following error:   no CUDA-capable device is detected  :-((( any other ideas?

Comment: @user3631541 : As the output gives Kernel driver in use: nvidia, the machine is running on the NVIDIA adapter. Maybe you have to adjust something in BIOS - otherwise I am running out of ideas ... sorry ... :)

Comment: I've got it running for once... more details are here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/732336/cannot-get-nvidia-gpu-running-on-my-hp-laptop-dual-graphics but after reboot I cannot start X anymore... . any ideas maybe? Thanks!