# Cannot get Nvidia GPU running on my HP laptop (dual graphics)

Tags: nvidia, bumblebee, xserver

I'm trying to get the GPU GeForce 940M on my new HP laptop ENVY 17-n101ng running (need CUDA eventually), but have somehow extreme troubles switching from Intel to Nvidia... I've installed nvidia-352 drivers, but could not just start using them... CUDA samples (e.g. deviceQuery) have been throwing errors... Hovewer, this command shows me both graphics cards:

```
lspci | grep -E "VGA|3D"
```

Then I've installed bumblebee:

```
sudo apt-get install bumblebee bumblebee-nvidia bbswitch-dkms primus
```

set zp the bumblebee.conf up according to my Nvidia drivers. I've been able to run

```
optirun glxgears
```

and

```
optirun nvidia-settings -c :8
```

and (for the 1st time) to see my GeForce 940M there!

However, I still could not start Nvidia samples... After all I've figured out the follolowing:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x86_64-linux-gnu_gl_conf
```

and selected there "manual" or "auto" mode (do not remember this now). And... CUDA has started to operate!!! But after reboot I see only black screen... Trying to start X server by "startx" from the console leads to the following error

```
Fatal server error: no screens found
```

Now I'm lost... How can I fix my desktop at the moment? How can I still use my Nvidia card? Seems to be a real pain in Ubuntu on laptops...

Any help is kindly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You could look into using nvidia prime with an indicator instead of bumblebee, as it is out dated.

You should install nvidia prime, remove bumblebee first

```
sudo apt-get purge bumblebee* nvidia*
sudo apt-get install nvidia-352
```

If needed, you could use this to get latest nvidia drivers.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-358
```

I don't have a optimus laptop anymore, but I remember prime because quite good and its supported by nvidia, so it works just fine.

[Here is some info on prime](http://www.webupd8.org/2014/01/prime-indicator-lets-you-quickly-switch.html)

Comment: Don't just add links to your answers, that is not allowed here, add the actual information (ie the PPA), plus you forgot to remove bumblebee first, as you are still new,I edited it this time but next time I will just down vote an answer missing so much information.

Comment: @markkirby : This was very friendly and kind of you - I very much appreciate your positive contribution ! :)

Comment: Sorry for the vast answer, will do better next time ;) thank you for correcting it.